# Obtain Windows Authenticated User.Identity.Name from web service (asmx) from JavaScript JSON request after ASP.NET sets user

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, asmx, windows-authentication

How can I retrieve the Windows authenticated user in an ASP.NET web service (asmx)?  This is what I thought would work, but "System.Web.UI.Page" doesn't exist.  This does however work in the code behind in an aspx page because "System.Web.UI.Page" has a value.  Note, I'm calling this web method from an ExtJS proxy read request.  It's requesting a JSON object in the JavaScript code.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public string GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin()
{
    string windowsLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    int hasDomain = windowsLogin.IndexOf(@"\");
    if (hasDomain > 0)
    {
        windowsLogin = windowsLogin.Remove(0, hasDomain + 1);
    }
    return windowsLogin;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can access like this

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Is there some other code or configuration required?  Right now, I have "<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>", but HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is an empty string.

Comment: FYI: I'm calling the web method from an ExtJS proxy read (JSON AJAX request), which might be getting called prior to the identity getting set.  Possibility?  How can I force my JavaScript to wait until the user identity is set?

Comment: +1 .. Okay, I figured it out.  Even though the web.config file had this configuration, I still had to configure IIS to turn it on so the Identity gets set.  In Windows XP > IIS Manager > Properties > Directory Security (tab) > Anonymous Access Edit > un-check "Anonymous Access" & check "Integrated Windows authentication".  After doing that, the value showed up.

Answer (score 6):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```